# Python Web Scraping "certificate verify failed"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to web scrape some text from a website, but I'm facing the well-known 'certificate verify failed' problem

I did some research, but I'm afraid that the knowledge to solve this issue is beyond my reach and that's why I ask for help:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 
               'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'} 
    
    page = 'https://www.bsmsupervisao.com.br/atividades-disciplinares-e-processos/acompanhe-os-processos/parecer/2018-001-pad'
    print(page)
        
    pageTree = requests.get(page, verify=False, headers=headers)
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
        
    my_Text = pageSoup.find_all("h3", {"class": "blue"}) 
        
    print(my_Text)
```

This is the error message:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.bsmsupervisao.com.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /atividades-disciplinares-e-processos/acompanhe-os-processos/parecer/2018-001-pad (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server, they block you, because there ia max number of retries.